# How to set scrollTop in React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I defined a `userRef` to set `scrollTop` for a Div tag:

```
const listRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

but I can't set scrollTop with this code:

```
listRef.scrollTop = listRef.current.scrollHeight;
```

returns this error: `Object is possibly 'null'`

Answer (score 0):

Set default value

```
const listRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(document.createElement('div'))
```

Use optional operater

```
listRef.scrollTop = current?.scrollHeight || 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize this state:

```
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);
```

Then add this inside ur useEffect hook:

```
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 300) {
    setShowButton(true);
  } else {
    setShowButton(false);
  }
});
```

And heres the scrollToTop function outside the useEffect hook:

```
const scrollToTop = () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};
```

Then just paste this html part inside ur react return loop:

```
{showButton && (
          <button onClick={scrollToTop} className="back-to-top">^
          </button>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) to make typescript only access the property if parent property doesn't have `null` or `undefined` value.

Also you probably forgot to use `current` property with ref.

```
const listRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

listRef.current?.scrollTop = listRef.current?.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score -2):

window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })